# Have some RewriteCond's affect multiple rules

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website where various parts [parse request URLs by themselves](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/70) and some don't (e.g. a vBulletin forum). The .htaccess I have to send requests to the appropriates scripts is:

```
# wiki, shop, admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)\.js
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ wiki/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/ /shop/shop.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/admincp/pkr/ /forum/admincp/pkr/pkr.php [NC,L]
```

This doesn't work as I expected. I forgot that the rewrite conditions are only applied to the first rule that follows them. The question is **How can I apply those *RewriteCond*itions to all those rules without having to copypaste them 4 times?**

---

What goes wrong is this:

- /shop/example is rewritten to /shop/shop.php
- /shop/shop.php is then rewritten again to /shop/shop.php (read: we have an infinite loop). This would not happen if this condition was applied to that rewrite rule, because /shop/shop.php is an actual file:

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

So yeah...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invert the expression and attach it to a breaking rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.js
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't understand Gumbo's answer so here is what I found what works:

Instead of matching *something* and executing more than one `RewriteRule` from that test, you can invert your match rule (such as using a ! sign) and if it doesn't find it, skip past X number of rules. Such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=2] # Skip the below X lines if the above test passes
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*) /resources/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico /resources/favicon.ico [L]
```

So if the HTTP_HOST starts with www.mydomain.com I want the two last RewriteRules to be processed. But what I'm doing is, if the HTTP_HOST does *not* start with www.mydomain.com, skip the next two rules. The first RewriteRule: `. - [S=2]` doesn't actually change anything, but the S=2 flag means skip the next X=2 rules.

A little bit of reverse logic if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the answer for the rest of us! +1

Comment: That's pretty cool but also a bit tricky, if someone adds a rewrite rule later and forgets to update the number of lines to skip you get unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

or Just make another condition like

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !shop.php
```

or even better

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(.*)\.php
```