# RewriteRule overrules second rule and GETs index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule which I thought worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/editor/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=editor&func=$2
```

When I do a `$_GET['lang']` on the first level (lang and page only), it returns the language. But if I try it on the second level (lang, page and func), I get `index.php`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what is first level and what is second level?
Note that the first rewrite rule is always true. . is a waildcard for 'any character', this includes the '/'

Comment: @Pinoniq the first rewriterule. Level is maybe a confusing thing to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a  `[L]` flag to cease processing after the first match, and your second rule would also be matched by the first. Since it is more specific, list it first, and include the `[L]`. Additionally, instead of greedy `(.*)` I recommend `([^/]+)` to match everything up to the next `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# List this first, with [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/editor/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=editor&func=$2 [L]
# Then URIs not containing editor/ will match the other rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

If CSS & images are failing, you probably need to move the `RewriteCond` beneath the `editor/` rule to be sure the conditions only apply to the least specific, catch-all match:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/editor/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=editor&func=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Yes! That gives me the right lang! Only my stylesheet and images aren't working. I have a base in my HTML.. How can I solve this?

Comment: @JayWit What do you mean a base in your HTML? a `<base href=''>` tag?  Add a `[L,R]` flag and attempt to request one of your CSS files directly to see where it gets rewritten to.  The `RewriteCond` ought to be taking care of that...

Comment: You may need to insert a breaking rule ahead of the `RewriteRule`s as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715765/have-some-rewriteconds-affect-multiple-rules

Comment: I get redirected to the `index.php?lang=nl&page=home`. The images and CSS aren't working both pages. The new solution provided doesn't work either :[

Comment: But where does `page=home` come from then? Do you have another rule writing to `home`?

Comment: In my PHP script I check if page is empty or not. If it is, it gets redirected to home

Comment: And you have _no other rules_? And interior directories have no other .htaccess files, or rules at the server config level? Comment out both `RewriteRule` and verify that your CSS works even then...

Comment: Then it works, strange! No other rules atm. This is really confusing, it loads some images, but not the one in `images` folder.. [Edit] I think thats because the other images are in deeper folders ex `uploads/files/images/`. Maybe the htaccess thinks the `images/image.jpg` is a request?

Comment: `/images/image.jpg` matches `^([^/]+)/(.*)$`. Perhaps you need to have the two lines of `RewriteCond` on both rules?

Comment: @Sylwester `^([^/]+)/(.*)$` also matches `uploads/files/images/`  which does work, due to `.*`.

Comment: @JayWit If you use the second solution above, and the images in `/images` are real files, it should not match. You may duplicate the two `RewriteCond` directives above the first `editor/` rule a well as above the catch-all, but I don't think that's going to help. I think you have something else getting in the way of the `images/` directory specifically.